# Show header menu by membership type in php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have 4 account types in my script.

Types are : User, doctor, uzman, hospital. What I want to do is normal user can see only few links on header menu and doctor, uzman and hospital users can see more links. Sorry for my bad english.

The codes like this:

```
    <nav id="menu">
            <a href="" style="background-image: url(static/img/logo.png)"></a>
            <ul>


                <?php if ($this->user->logged()): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="giris-yap"></i> Hesabım</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim" >Profil Sayfası</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/duzenle" >Profil Düzenle</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/fotograf-duzenle" >Fotoğraf</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/sifre-guncelle" >Şifre İşlemleri</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/hizmetler" >Hizmetler</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/sosyal-medya" >Sosyal Ağ</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/makaleler" >Makaleler</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/videolar" >Videolar</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/sorular" >Sorular</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="hesabim/randevular" >Randevu Talepleri</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li ><a href="cikis" ><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> ÇIKIŞ YAP</a></li
                </li>
                <?php else: ?>

                <li>
                    <a href="giris-yap">Giriş Yap</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="uye-ol">Üye Ol</a>
                </li>
                <li ><a href="uye-ol/doktor" style="color: rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important">Doktor musunuz?</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

and I want to do : normal user will see only first 3 links and others account types will see all.

Can you help me on this please ?

Comment: show your $this->session->set_userdata()  how you store type in session

Answer (score 0):

you can use session for this. 
In your controller at login function you can add the type of user in session like this :

```
$this->session->set_userdata('type', 'doctor');
```

then in your view you can check it like this :

```
$type = $this->session->userdata('type');
if ($type === 'doctor) {
    //nav menu for doctor
}
```